# Crash when combining QFileSystemModel with QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qfilesystemmodel

I have QfileSysteModel and QSortFilterProxyModel. When I try to call `QfileSysteModel.filePath` to get the current index of the file Error occurs as `core Dump`. Here is a piece of code

```
    le = QLineEdit()
    lv = QListView()

    file_model = QFileSystemModel()
    file_model.setRootPath(QtCore.QDir.rootPath())

    proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel(
        recursiveFilteringEnabled=True,
        filterRole=QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel.FileNameRole)
    proxy_model.setSourceModel(file_model)
    lv.setModel(self.proxy_model)
```

It works well, but when I try to call any methods of the `QFileSystemModel` Core Dumps. for example

```
filepath  = file_model.filePath(lv.currentIndex())
```

How can I use any method of the `QfileSystemModel`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lv = QtWidgets.QListView()

        self.file_model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
        self.file_model.setRootPath(QtCore.QDir.rootPath())

        self.proxy_model = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel(
            recursiveFilteringEnabled=True,
            filterRole=QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel.FileNameRole)
        self.proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.file_model)
        self.lv.setModel(self.proxy_model)
        root_index = self.file_model.index(QtCore.QDir.rootPath())
        proxy_index = self.proxy_model.mapFromSource(root_index)
        self.lv.setRootIndex(proxy_index)
        self.lv.doubleClicked.connect(self.navigate)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(le)
        lay.addWidget(self.lv)


    def navigate(self):

        # Get the path of file or folder
        filepath  = self.file_model.filePath(self.lv.currentIndex())
        print(filepath)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: what is `self.files`? ....

Comment: Sorry for this mistake. I modified it, it is the file_model. I will try to provide a short cut of the code since it is long code

Comment: I don't get any errors, if you want help you must provide an MRE.

Comment: An MRE must be small but the most important thing is that it must be reproducible.

Comment: Thanks, I provided a sample code. The problem is I can no longer use file_model methods. Hope you can help

Comment: @ArcZezo See my answer. All the code was actually not necessary to understand the problem. However it is generally better to provide full code when asking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with a proxy model, the `ModelIndex` of the proxy differs from the index in the source model. Use [`mapToSource()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractproxymodel.html#mapToSource) to convert from proxy model to source model.

In your case, it would probably look like this:

```
# alternative one: do not reference proxy_model directly
filepath = file_model.filePath(lv.model().mapToSource(lv.currentIndex()))
# alternative two:
filepath = file_model.filePath(self.proxy_model.mapToSource(lv.currentIndex()))
```